# How can I access files from app sandbox on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a react native app which generates data which is limited to it's sandbox as apple policy. Now I want to download and upload these data files in that app sandbox when opening google drive on browsers or Google drive app.

If not possible could I copy the sandbox files and paste to the device storage so it can be accessible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the iFunbox for that

1. download https://www.i-funbox.com/
2. Open the App menu
3. Click the app and pop up will shown
4. Click the Open sandbox

PS : this only applicable for App that not downloaded from Appstore, or you need to jailbreak in order to do that